# g++ compiled application doesn't work

Tags: g++

I wrote a simulation code with C++ and compiled it into an executable using `g++`. However, the output file doesn't do anything when double clicked. I checked "allow file to be used as executable" as well but still, nothing happens. Any alternate ways I should try or is something wrong?

EDIT: It is set to run as a WINE application even though I deleted WINE using `apt-get purge` a while ago. Can it be the problem? Maybe I should try another program to run it with. What should it be actually set as default?

EDIT 2: I performed the compiling using:

`$ sudo g++ -o main main.cpp`

It is a simple command-line app that has no GUI.

Comment: How exactly did you compile it into an executable? Please [edit] your question to include the command you used. Is it a command-line only program or a GUI application?

Comment: @steeldriver added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application has no GUI (I.E. only does console output), you would not see anything because a terminal is not opened when double clicking an executable in the file manager. However, your application should run in the background.

You can run the executable from an existing shell by calling it with `./path/to/executable`

The second, more complex option would be to make a desktop file to launch the application from the file ex and set it to show the terminal output.

Suppose I have a very simple application such as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    std::cout << "hello bob" << std::endl;
    system("read moo"); // pause for input at the end.
    return 0;
}
```

And I compile it with `g++ foo.cpp` which by default outputs an `a.out` file.

Then just create a `foo.desktop` file containing

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Awesome App
Terminal=true
Exec=/path/to/a.out
```

which one could then set executable then double-click from the file navigator and see the terminal output. That is how application shortcuts are built in menus and how they get to have a friendly name and icons.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it in a terminal. If it's a command line program you won't be able to do a lot just by double clicking the executable in a file manager. Run the following in a terminal:

```
cd /path/to/directory
```

Replacing `/path/to/directory` with the path to the directory where your binary is in;

```
sudo chmod +x binaryName
```

To make sure your binary is executable (replace binaryName with its name);

```
./binaryName
```

To execute it.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to `chmod` gcc/g++ built executables: if they aren't already executable then something else has gone wrong (skipped link phase, filesystem doesn't support the executable bit, yadda yadda)

Comment: Ok, but the OP messed with file permissions, so it's good to make sure.